# What is the pwa-node type launch configuration on VSCode?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, visual-studio-code, terminology

I noticed that the default launch configuration generated by VSCode for npm debugging (Launch via NPM) sets the configuration type as "pwa-node" by default.

Adding "Launch via NPM" configuration:

[image: Adding Launch via NPM configuration]

Generated configuration type:

[image: generated type]

I've searched a bit but didn't find the meaning of this (maybe something related to Progressive Web Apps?).

Does anyone know the meaning of "pwa-node" and why "pwa-node" and not "node"?

Comment: PWA means progressive web app[s], not specific to vscode.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

### The `type` attribute

The `type` attribute specifies the type of debugger to use for this launch configuration. Every installed debug extension introduces a type: `node` for the built-in Node debugger, for example, or `php` and `go` for the PHP and Go extensions.

---

### `type : pwa-node`

Javascript Debugger is a built-in extension for debugging in VS code. This extension is installed and enabled by default in the latest versions of VS code. The `"type": "pwa-node"` comes from the Javascript Debugger (Nightly), the preview version. The `pwa-` prefix is used to distinguish which debugger should be used.

The `"type": "pwa-node"` is added to your `launch.json` when you click `Node.js(Preview)` instead of `Node.js` in the drop down menu while creating the `launch.json` file from the debugging section of the sidebar. **Note: See 2022 update below**.

If you open the `defaultSettings.json` of your VS code, you can see the settings(enabled) for the preview version, they look like following:

```
"debug.javascript.usePreview": true,
"debug.javascript.usePreviewAutoAttach": true,
```

If you want to use this nightly version of the debugger extension, you need to disable the built-in debugger and install the nightly version from the marketplace. To do so, follow these steps:

1. Open the extensions view and search for `@builtin @id:ms-vscode.js-debug`
2. Right click and disable the extension.
3. Now search for the nightly extension by typing: `@id:ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly`
4. Click install and restart the VS code.

Now you can debug the Typescript and Javascript code using the JavaScript Debugger (Nightly).

If you get the error that `debug type 'pwa-node' is not supported`, remove the following settings from your `settings.json`:

```
"debug.node.useV3": true,
"debug.chrome.useV3": true
```

---

### `type : node`

If you want the previous behaviour, that is `"type": "node"`, click `Node.js` instead of `Node.js(Preview)` in the drop down menu while creating the `launch.json` file from the debugging section of the sidebar. You can also just type `"type": "node"` by hand in the `launch.json` instead of doing it from the menu, it won't make any difference.

If you have made the above changes for the nightly version of the Javascript Debugger, you should undo them for the built-in Javascript Debugger to work properly.

**Update 2022**

As of July 2022, `pwa-node` is not preview anymore. Now it's the default debugger. There is no more `Node.js(Preview)` option. However, selecting `Node.js` produces a `launch.json` file that has `"type": "pwa-node"`. The older extensions will be deprecated.

Comment: @OldGeezer, as mentioned in the answer, `pwa-node` is a nightly build which is also known as preview build. `node` is a regular, more stable build. Use `pwa-node` if you want the latest features like progressive web apps, but it may not be production ready yet.

Comment: 2022 update: When clicking `create a launch.json file` under the big blue Run and Debug, the options are Node, VS Code Extension Development, Web App (Chrome), Web App (Edge), Install an extension for Javascript.... There is no more Preview option. However, selecting Node produces a launch.json file that has `"type": "pwa-node"`. Is something amiss?

Comment: @OldGeezer, thanks for pointing it out. `pwa-node` is not preview anymore. Now it's the default debugger. The older extensions will be deprecated.

Answer (score 21):

The `pwa-` prefix is/was a way to target VS Code's [new JavaScript debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug), which at the time was named [vscode-pwa](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pwa).

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/pull/32

> Talking with Kai and Rob, something we want to do is make the PWA extension
> a drop-in replacement for the existing two Chrome and Node debug extensions.
> Therefore we want to have the PWA extension be able to read and support the
> existing configuration settings, and be invoked by launching the `chrome`
> and `node` types. More work, coming soon in a followup PR, will
> be needed to actually deal with these settings.
>
> This also moved the build to a Gulp system, supporting NLS and matching
> the existing extensions. Part of the build is the ability to have the types
> and commands be prefixed with `pwa-`: running `gulp` will generate an extension
> that registers types `pwa-node` and `pwa-chrome`, while `gulp --drop-in` will
> remove these prefixes. This lets us develop and debug the extension using the
> existing packages, until such time as we want to start dogfooding it.

Also here they talk about how to use the targeting mechanism: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/85984

Comment: Does anyone know what the `PWA` acronym stands for? (In the context I've seen it in, it doesn't appear to mean "progressive web apps", which is common meaning of that acronym in web development.)

Comment: @robenkleene Might really just be "Progressive Web Apps". See the linked logo (resources/pwa.png) in this commit https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/commit/f73d6fc08?short_path=b1dca80#diff-b1dca80b2. It is a logo for PWA. Some of the commits [09c9ce22e](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/commit/09c9ce22e) also contains codes using ServiceWorkers, CacheStore and Puppeteer. Perhaps this was originally created for debugging PWA apps. See also [efa26ae84](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug/commit/efa26ae84), when it is renamed from CDP (Code Debug Protocol?) to PWA

Comment: Yeah, but **pwa-node** sounds like a nonsense.

Comment: Can we prepend `pwa-` to any type and it will point to using the new JS Debugger?