# "Could not read source map" errors when connecting to Node debugger (Next.js)

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, next.js

I'm following the [Next.js debugging docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/debugging) to set up my local debugging environment.

"Step 1: Start Next.js in debug mode" is working fine:

```
> cross-env NODE_OPTIONS='--inspect' next dev

Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/e4bb955d-e3b2-4849-b6e7-0248e6a3d53e
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Loaded env from C:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\.env.local
ready - started server on http://localhost:3000
info  - Using external babel configuration from C:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\babel.config.js
event - compiled successfully
```

But on "Step 2: Connect to the debugger" I get these errors in VSCode Debug Console:

```
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/markj/workspace/my-app/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/path-to-regexp/index.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\path-to-regexp\index.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/markj/workspace/my-app/node_modules/@next/react-refresh-utils/ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\ReactRefreshWebpackPlugin.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/markj/workspace/my-app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/markj/workspace/my-app/node_modules/@next/react-refresh-utils/loader.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\loader.js.map'
Could not read source map for file:///C:/Users/markj/workspace/my-app/node_modules/@next/react-refresh-utils/internal/ReactRefreshModule.runtime.js: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\markj\workspace\my-app\node_modules\@next\react-refresh-utils\internal\ReactRefreshModule.runtime.js.map'
```

Unsurprisingly with these errors when I try to attach breakpoints it says "Unbound breakpoint".

Environment:

- Windows 10.0.19042
- Node.js 12.20.0
- Next.js 10.0.2
- VSCode 1.51.1

Any help or ideas are much appreciated!

Answer (score 12):

This is essentially caused by VSCode debugging files it shouldn't try and debug, i.e. node_modules. There are a few github issues on this, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103006) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/107637). That I found useful. Essentially the fix is to stop VSCode from caring about these files and you do this by setting [`"type":"pwa-node"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63662561/542251) and add:

```json
"resolveSourceMapLocations": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/",
    "!/node_modules/**"
],
```

To your `launch.json` under `.vscode`

Comment: I'm getting `Property resolveSourceMapLocations is not allowed.` if I add this to a debug configuration.

Comment: This solution also works in a web app development scenario (here vite + preact), except that you shouldn't use `pwa-node` as type.