# vuejs3 debugging on Visual Studio Code not working

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, vuejs3, vue-cli, vscode-debugger

I have recently moved over to Vuejs3 and my debugging setup stopped working. The breakpoints don't get triggered. I am using the same config files as before and not sure if something changed with this release.

- Debugger for Chrome Extension: v4.12.12
- VsCode: 1.56.2
- Vue CLI v3
- Platform: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "vuejs: pwa-chrome",
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "vuejs: chrome",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
        "breakOnLoad": true,
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
          "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
        }
      }
    ]
}
```

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    devtool: 'source-map'
  }
}
```

Comment: Setting breakpoints in Chrome works and triggers a break in vscode. However vscode still claims for its breakpoint that "Breakpoint set but not yet bound"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had to change my launch.json file to the below. Apparently the pwa- prefix is a way to target VS Code's new JavaScript debugger. See [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63442436/what-is-the-pwa-node-type-launch-configuration-on-vscode). The old debugger no longer works on this platform.
Hope this will help somebody.

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "type": "pwa-chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:8080",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was in similar situation and couldn't find relevant resolutions:

**Quick Answer:**
After upgrade to VS Code 1.56.2, make sure to remove old breakpoints and create new breakpoint and at-least have 1 breakpoint and launch.json available.

**Lengthy details:**

I have similar issue for python scripts when I start the "debugger bar" I see it for a couple of seconds the top debugging bar and then it disappears. Bu then no message on the console, nothing. I tried reinstalling VS Code, enabling/disabling extension, various restart.

- OS and Version: Mac OSX Version 11.4 (20F71)
- VS Code Version: 1.56.2
- Extension: Python v2021.5.842923320 by Microsoft

**RootCause:**

What I did know for sure that I updated my VS Code, and after that this mysterious issue start happening, so when to release log of VS Code 1.56.2. I found below release log

> Debug view displayed on break#
>
> The default value of the debug.openDebug setting is now
> openOnDebugBreak so that on every breakpoint hit, VS Code will open
> the Debug view. The Debug view is also displayed on first session
> start.

So VS code Version 1.56 release, debugger will only show when at-least 1 breakpoint is found. However, looks like there is issue with their internal code checking for historical breakpoint data after VS Code upgrade..

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_debug-view-displayed-on-break

Comment: I have removed all breakpoints restarted everything and reset the breakpoints. Still does not work. When I set the breakpoint in Chrome it actually triggers the hold. Also my breakpoint claims "Breakpoint set but not yet bound"

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 paths in the sourceMapPathOverrides. It is working for me.

```
"sourceMapPathOverrides": {
  "webpack:///./src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
  "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works after removing sourceMapPathOverrides:

```
            // "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
            //   "webpack:///src/*.vue": "${webRoot}/*.vue",
            //   "webpack:///./src/*.js": "${webRoot}/*.js",
            // }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since everyone uses different `vue-cl`i versions and `webpack` versions, I will provide a more efficient solution here. You can configure the `writeToDisk` field in your devServer to be true,  like this:

webpack5:

```js
devServer: {
    devMiddleware: {
      writeToDisk: true,
    },
  },
```

webpack < 5:

```js
devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true
  }
```

You also need to change your source-map configuration to `devtool: 'source-map'` instead of `devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map'`
The faster sourceMap format will cause more information to be lost, making your VScode unable to determine the resource path.

Then, after you execute `npm run dev`, there will be an extra `dist` folder in your project which contains source-map files,

the source-map files Include the following fields:

```js
 "sources": [
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/App.vue?01fe",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?774b",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/App.vue?763f",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/components/HelloWorld.vue?6c98",
        "webpack://mydeb/src/App.vue",
        "webpack://mydeb/src/components/HelloWorld.vue",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/App.vue",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/components/HelloWorld.vue",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/main.js",
        "webpack://mydeb/./src/App.vue?81d5",
    ]
```

`mydeb` is the name field I configured in the package,
According to this information, I configure `launch.json` like this:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
                "webpack://mydeb/src/*.vue": "${webRoot}/src/*.vue",
                "webpack://mydeb/./src/*.js": "${webRoot}/src/*.js",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What you mean by package name? What would be mydeb really?

Comment: @MateusSarmento package name  is name field in package.json